# Cannot find module "service" (with spaces)

Tags: angular

[Sublime Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY8lv.png)

I don't understand why am I getting this error. I am including the correct name.
Any help is appropriated.

Comment: Your service is not in the same folder as your component, but in one level above.

Comment: `../get-mock-data.service`

Comment: I was under the impression that using "../" would find the find. So, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: @Ploppy Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service is not in the same folder as your component, but two levels above (`/layout/task1`).

So set proper relative path when importing:

```
import { getMockDataService } from '../../get-mock-data.service';
```